# How to check all files in a directory except one file in Groovy language

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to search a word in every file in a directory but I want to exclude my logfile.

My code is something like this

```
user input: search test C:\Users\Desktop\test\Groovy
```

My code

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def terminal_log = new File("terminal.log")
def terminal_log_path = terminal_log.getName()
def fas = ""
def file2_path = ""
def cmd = System.console().readLine 'Enter command: '
String[] csplice = cmd.split(" ");
if(csplice.length == 3){
    def first_parameter = csplice[0]
    def second_parameter = csplice[1]
    def third_parameter = csplice[2]
    if(first_parameter == "search"){
        def file = new File(third_parameter)
        if(file.exists()){
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                file.eachFile(FILES) { f -> 
                    fas = "/"+f+"/"
                    File file2 = new File(fas)
                    file2_path = file2.getName()
                    if(!file2_path == terminal_log_path){
                        file2.eachLine{ line ->
                            if(line.contains(second_parameter)){
                                println "This file contains this word"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                println "Not a directory"
            }
        }else{
            println "Not exists"
        }
    }else{
        println "Invalid command"
    }
}else{
    println "Invalid command"
}
```

This block here is not working

```
if(!file2_path == terminal_log_path){
```

Is there any documentation that I can read to exclude a specific file while checking every files in a directory?

Many thanks

EDIT:
the directory of the user input has the logfile (terminal.log)
terminal.log exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (file2_path != terminal_log_path) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if (!(file2_path == terminal_log_path)) {
   ...
}
```

E.g. you can run the following code to see the result of applying the  "Not" operator to a string in Groovy:

```
def file2_path = "/i/am/path/"
println (!file2_path) // prints false as file2_path is not an empty string
```

For more info, you can refer to [the official Groovy doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_not_operator) on that topic:

> The "not" operator is represented with an exclamation mark (!) and inverts the result of the underlying boolean expression. In particular, it is possible to combine the not operator with the Groovy truth:

```
    assert (!true)    == false
    assert (!'foo')   == false
    assert (!'')      == true
```

Comment: `if !()` won't even compile

Comment: @injecteer ah, I just missed the outer parens. Fixed, thanks!